# Fetch from a text file with syntax in

Tags: c#, winforms, text-files

I'm currently working on a Windows Form (C#) project where I need to store information in several textfiles. Just doing that is probably no problem and I get loads of results on Google. However, I can't seem to find a way to exclude and include things from the textfile based on syntax.

The program itself is supposed to create a verbal agreement depending on what is included in your order. So I need to catch only specifik part of the file; i.e:

**NewCustomer.txt**

```
#Introduction#
Today we have decided that you are our customer... Yay!  
-Break-
#BuyFood#
You have decided to buy %foodItem% from us for the price of %priceInDollars% dollars.  
-Break-
#BuyCar#
You have decided to buy a %selectedCar% from us for the price of %priceInDollars% dollars.
-Break-


#Ending#  
My name is %agentName%, thank you for your purchase! 
-Break-
```

I then want to extract information from this file and lay in a popup window line for line. So that the agent will see something like;

```
---AGREEMENT-------------------------------------------------|_|[]|X|
| Today we have decided that you are our customer... Yay!           |
| You have decided to buy pizza from us for the price of 12 dollars.|
| My name is Some Dude, thank you for your purchase!                |
|                                                                   |
|                                                             [OK]  |
|___________________________________________________________________|
```

I am however **completely** stuck at this point, and as I have never used textfiles or fetch functions in any of my earlier projects I have no idea where to begin.
How do I go about to accomplish such a thing?

*Please do note that the syntax and all variables are examples. I have no idea what a proper syntax for such a file would look like, and this is what I created to show you my idea.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store structured data as text you have two options: **jSon** and **XML** in both cases you don't need to worry about the structure of the string that is being created and parsed. You create a class:

```
public class MyStrings
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then you serialize your data using for example `NewtonSoft.Json` or any other Json or XML serializers.

```
var data = new List<MyStrings>()
{
    new MyStrings()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Text = "Today we have decided that you are our customer... Yay!"
    },
    new MyStrings()
    {
        Id = 2,
        Text = "You have decided to buy {0} from us for the price of {1} dollars."
    }
}

var stringToWriteInFile = JsonConvert.Serialize(data);
```

The result is then an string which you can write in a file and later do the exact reverse to get your data back.

Comment: I see! I have a question about this though:  
If the agreement would be updated in the future, would it be possible to edit the raw XML file in say Notepadpp, or will I have to edit the source code in that scenario?

Comment: Both jSon and XML are human readable which means you can edit them later. XML is better in this aspect.

Comment: I see!
I also have a question about the implementation of this solution:
Where should I put the "data" and "stringToWriteInFile" variables?

Should they be implemented in the main form somehow, or directly in the MyString Class?

To be quite honest I have no idea what this really is or does.
Is there a documentation of this somewhere that could give me some insight in how to use it?

Comment: As to where to put it, I don't know it depends on the structure of your project and part of the software architecture which is an art. And to learn how to do it you should search the web. For XML you can see http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/introduction/ And accept the answer if you think it's good :)

Comment: Yes, now that I have all the necessary information I believe I'm good to go.
Thank you very much for taking your time to reply and help me out!